# Can we implement Polymorphism in struct?

Tags: oop, c#-4.0

I am sure it is a low level question but I am not able to find the answer to this question.

I am of the opinion that struct don't support Polymorphism but Senior of mine(in an interview) says it is possible.

Can someone please tell?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code ? just to argue your post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean runtime polymorphism (method overload). I don't think you can do that with Structs since structs don't support inheritance.

You might want to refer to the [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) or [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664473(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: do you mean runtime polymorphism(method overriding).does it mean we can do compile time polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm I am thinking about the fact that a structure can implement an interface...

For example:

```
public interface IPoint
{
   int X {get;set;}
   int Y {get;set;}
}
public struct Point : IPoint 
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set;}
}

public struct AnotherPoint : IPoint
{
     public int X { get; set; }
     public int Y { get; set; }
}

public static void Main () {
    var arr = new IPoint [2];
    arr [0] = new Point () { X = 2 };
    arr [1] = new AnotherPoint () { X = 7 };

    foreach (var p in arr) {
        Console.WriteLine (p.X);
    }
    Console.ReadKey ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do compile time polymorphism but not Runtime.I tried a code below and to my surprise it WORKED!

I tried the code and compile time polymorphism is allowed .Code is below but then why runtime polymorphism is not allowed I didnt get that but for now ,I think i got the solution.

Any comments or guidline are appreciated.

```
using System;
struct SimpleStruct
{
    private int xval;
    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return xval;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 100)
                xval = value;
        }
    }
    public void DisplayX()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The stored value is: {0}", xval);
    }
    public void DisplayX(int a)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("The stored value is: {0}", a);
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SimpleStruct ss = new SimpleStruct();
        ss.X = 5;
        ss.DisplayX();
        ss.DisplayX(3);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile Time polymorphism (function overloading and operator overloading) is supported by structures but not run time polymorphism. Structures don't support inheritence and runtime polymorphism is achived using the concept virtual functions on base and derived class.

Since, Structures don't support inheritence therefore it can't support run time polymorphism.